# Can I specify the output folder for assets?

Tags: parceljs

I have a project with this structure:

```
src
 |- index.pug
 | - layout
 |     |- index.less
 | - scripts
 |     |- index.js
```

For now, when I run `parcel build src/index.pug`, all the files are bundled and I've got this on the distribution folder:

```
dist
  |- index.html
  |- index.12345.css
  |- index.12345.js
```

When I was spected something like:

```
dist
  |- index.html
  |- layout
  |    |- index.12345.css
  |- scripts
  |    |- index.12345.js
```

So, my question is: Can I specify the output path for my css, js and images using ParcelJS?

Comment: Don't think you can, non entry point assets are hashed and moved to root (folder structure is flattened): https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/872

Comment: You might find a solution among the Namer plugins: https://parceljs.org/plugin-browser/?type=%22namer%22&page=0&filter=%22%22&includeOfficial=false

Answer (score 7):

Parcel doesn't support this feature out of the box, but I've developed a plugin for it. Check it out https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-custom-dist-structure

It is suitable for all types of web/node development projects, it will generate the dist structure you specify while also handle your imports.

Let me know what you think!

Comment: Had some issues when changing files that referenced images, but once I restarted `npx parcel serve index.html`, it worked fine. If it becomes more of a problem, I'll see if I can reproduce it consistently and submit an issue.

Comment: A very good plugin, but unfortunately it somehow does not change the reference to css in html (works for scripts though): https://github.com/VladimirMikulic/parcel-plugin-custom-dist-structure/issues/36

Comment: It's a cool plugin but parcel 1 is deprecated and this plugin doesn't currently support parcel 2, sadly.

Comment: @EricXinZhang your issue has been fixed :)

Comment: @RomanStarkov thanks for your intereset. A few days ago I migrated two of my Parcel plugins to version 2 and I will hopefully soon migrate parcel-plugin-custom-dist-structure too.

Comment: @VladimirMikulic That's great news, I hope you do! We use your plugin with parcel 1 and it does a great job.

Answer (score 5):

With version 1 it's not supported. This is supposed to be available in version 2 through user plugins. See https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/233